# Why is there water build up in my soffits?

Tags: soffit, ice

We just had our windows, gutters, soffits and siding done a year and a half ago. We never had issues with our old soffits with leakage. Last winter we had a little bit of an issue with water and rust stains on our new soffits. The guy came back and said he wasn't sure but scrubbed off the rust looking stain. Now its worse and the ice is coming through the pots lights on our soffits. We have a bungalow home with a slight pitch. We have a membrane rolled out roof and never had issues with it. Like I said, only issues since we have had the gutters and soffits installed. We also have a drip from under the top board on the siding. After the gutters were installed, I did notice that the flashing from the gutter that goes up inside the drip edge was not fully sealed. They did caulk most of it but seemed like a bad job and had some openings. When water melts from the ice build up, can it go up behind the drip edge into the soffit?

Comment: How about some pictures of what your're seeing.

Comment: Does this only happen with snow, or rain too? Is it all the way around the house or just one side?

Comment: Have you made sure your gutters are clean? If they're clogged, water will stand and if the gutter gets full enough then yes, it will rise up through tight openings and go where you don't expect it to be.